# Command not found whenever a specific command is called in discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So, most of the commands in my discord bot work, but whenever I call this specific commands, I get the "Command is not found". This is the code for those specific commands:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        print("Music paused")
        voice.pause()
        await ctx.send("Music paused")
    else:
        print("Music not playing")
        await ctx.send("Music not playing, failed pause")


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_paused():
        print("Resumed Music")
        voice.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resumed music")
    else:
        print("Music is not paused")
        await ctx.send("Music not paused, failed to resume")


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        print("Music stopped")
        voice.stop()
        await ctx.send("Music stopped")
    else:
        print("Music not playing")
        await ctx.send("Music not playing, failed to stop")
```

I am not sure what the problem could be, as all of the other commands inside the bot work just fine.

Comment: Indent your code with four spaces for best formatting.

Comment: well for me when I tried it it worked. One thing you need to do though is by `voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` you need to change it to `voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)`

Comment: only things that could make it say commandnotfound, is if you are spelling it wrong, wrong spacing, punctuation maybe, or if you ran the wrong code. Those are the only reasons you can get CommandNotFOund error

Comment: The code was fine, I copied and pasted the same code into a new file and it worked, it is really odd

Comment: what is your command prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_command_error` function.

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(add a custom message, or you can do f"{error}".)
        return
```

If you would like to have a custom error for each command, you can use.

```
@commandname.error
async def commandname_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errorname):
        await ctx.send(add a custom message, or you can do f"{error}".)
```